# Dependency Injection with factory method .net

Tags: c#, .net-core, dependency-injection

I have a structure like below. I need ideas on how to clearly record all instances. Do you think Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection library is suitable for these?

```
 public interface IRules
 { 
   void Do();
 }
```

Implementation :

```
public class MyRules:IRules
{
   public void Do()
   {
     //Something;
   }
}
```

Businnes Interface:

```
public  interface IRulesOperation
{
    void Do();
}
```

Businnes class:

```
public class RulesOperation:IRulesOperation
    {
        private readonly IRules rules;
        private readonly IConfiguration conf;
        public RulesOperation(IRules rules,IConfiguration conf)
        {
            this.conf=conf;
            this.rules = rules;
        }
        public void Do()
        {
            rules.Do();
        }
    }
```

Main Class:

```
public class App
{
        IRulesOperation rules;
        
        public App(IRulesOperation rules)
        {
            this.rules=rules;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Implementation of `IRules` is an interface? Not sure if this is a mistake or you intended it. I don't think the intended use of an interface default implementation is to hide an inherited member.

Comment: Sorry, ı updated IRules implementation. It must have been class.

Comment: What is your concern? Why would a DI container (microsoft or not) not work for you? There is nothing particularly outstanding in this code example to think you may have some edge case.

Comment: I have concern about how can ı register "IConfiguration" in the RulesOperation class.

Comment: Not an issue. If you're in ASP.Net Core, you don't have to do anything, just inject it. Otherwise, there is a little bit of boilerplate code you have to include, which you can google easily.